# How to properly round half down a decimal number?

Tags: python, math, decimal, rounding

I am trying to round half down a number, but my program doesn't want to round half down but up.

For instance, I have 0.0498512222 
I want to get 0.049, but the program round half up and give me 0.050

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, signal, json, time
import random
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_DOWN
num = 0.049852124
num = Decimal(num)
numCoins = Decimal(num.quantize(Decimal('0.001'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_DOWN))
numCoins = float(numCoins)
print numCoins
```

I don't know how to resolve this error, because it's for a cryptocurrency bot, and the `numCoins` is the number of a coin that I have. If the program round half up I'll get an error like 'Account has insufficient balance for requested action' because I can't sell more than I have.

Comment: It might help elucidate the situation if the intermediate results are displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import sys, signal, json, time
import random
import math
num = 0.049852124 
# where 1 is in the position you want to truncate
numCoins = num - math.fmod(num, 0.001)
print numCoins # 0.049
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Glad to help! Notice this method will merely truncate the float at a  given position and not perform true "rounding"

Answer (score 2):

ROUND_HALF_DOWN is round ***half*** down, as in when a number is exactly halfway between two options of what to round to, it rounds down. Everything else rounds to nearest. You are significantly above the halfway point between 0.049 and 0.050, so you round to nearest.

If you want to round *everything* down, that's ROUND_DOWN, not ROUND_HALF_DOWN.

Also, if you want decimal arithmetic, using floats is a mistake from the start. Instead of `num = 0.049852124`, you should use avoid floats entirely with something like `num = Decimal('0.049852124')`, and you should avoid producing a float at the end.